# Когда выделяется память под автоматические переменные?

Tags: c++, c, выделение-памяти, локальные-переменные

В книгах пишут, что когда выполнение программы заходит в функцию, то выделяется память под все автоматические переменные функции при вхождении и она освобождается при завершении этой функции. Например:

```
void function(int value)
{
     int a = 10;

     // ...
     
     double b = 6.3;
     
     for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
     {
          // ...
     }

}
```

Память под все переменные (`value`, `a`, `b`, `i`) выделяется при вхождении в функцию или при объявлении?

Comment: при вызове(что значит вхождение для вас, я не знаю). При вызове выполняется код, написанной в функции, а для этого выделяется отдельный фрейм, после выхода(после выполнения кода функции) из которого все локалные объекты уничтожаются  (вернее, при выходе)

Comment: Локальные переменные могут храниться в регистрах, и не занимать никакой памяти.

Comment: Четкого ответа я так и не увидел.

Comment: @Danny, считайте что в момент вызова. При объявлении функции компилятор подсчитывает, на сколько сдвигать стек. В начале функции есть код, который смещает указатель стека на такую величину, чтобы в выделенной памяти можно было сохранить все регистры, используемые функцией при своей работе и все локальные переменные. Однако, если функция маленькая, то оптимизатор может построить такой код, что ни сохранять регистры, ни использовать память под несколько локальных переменных (которые он разместит в регистрах, которые по соглашениям о связях можно не сохранять) не потребуется.

Comment: @insolor, регистры тоже являются  ячейками памяти, только она не доступна программисту, а используется самим процессором. Не занимать память в оперативной системе, это не значит не занимать память. Не занимать память в стеке, это не  значит не занимать память вообще

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, обычно про регистры не говорят «память». Регистры — это регистры, а под «памятью» понимают именно внешнюю память. Кроме того, регистры не адресуемы, у них не адреса, поэтому называть их «ячейками памяти» было бы не очень правильно.

Comment: @eanmos, в общем случае это не так. На многих микроконтроллерах регистры адресуемы, например у ARV ячейки линейной памяти с адресами 0...31 соответствую регистрам общего назначения R0...R31

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, ух ты, я не знал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Память может быть выделена во время вызова функции, когда указатель на вершину стека сдвигают на определенное количество байт, чтобы зарезервировать место под локальные переменные. Например, код

   ```
   void function(int value)
   {
         int a = 10;
         double b = 6.3;
   }
   ```

   будет скомпилирован (`-O0 -mno-red-zone -m32`) в

   ```
   function(int):
       push    ebp
       mov     ebp, esp

       // Резервируем 16 байт под локальные переменные. Помните,
       // что на x86 стек растет по направлению к младшим адресам,
       // поэтому мы ВЫЧИТАЕМ из регистра esp.
       sub     esp, 16

       mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 10
       fld     QWORD PTR .LC0
       fstp    QWORD PTR [ebp-16]
       nop
       leave
       ret
   ```

   На практике в системах с System V ABI такое выделение памяти под локальные переменные вообще не происходит. По соглашению вызываемая функция может свободно использовать 128 байт после указателя на вершину стека для хранения своих локальных переменных. Эта свободная область в 128 байт называется [Red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)).

   *Именно поэтому, чтобы продемонстрировать выделение памяти в примере выше, пришлось передать компилятору флаг `mno-red-zone`*.
2. Локальная переменная может быть помещена в регистр, тогда память под нее вообще не будет выделена.

   Мы можем использовать ключевое слово `register` при объявлении переменной, чтобы *посоветовать* компилятору поместить переменную в регистр. Хотя такие советы компилятор по большей части игнорирует.
3. Копилятор может встроить значение локальной переменной в саму инструкцию процессора, тогда память под переменную также не будет выделена.
4. В процессе оптимизации компилятор может вообще избавится от некоторых локальных переменных, следовательно, и память для них выделена не будет.

   Например, следующий код

   ```
   int foo(void) {
       int a = 4;
       int b = 9;
       return a + b;
   }
   ```

   будет скомпилирован (`-O2`) в

   ```
    foo:
        mov     eax, 13
        ret
   ```